# custom search engine query returning false phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a custom search engine with phpMyAdmin and have been searching for hours to try and find a fix to my query returning false. I am new to both php and sql so it would be amazing if someone could explain to me what i'm doing wrong!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Results</title>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
  </head>
</html>
<?php

$search = $_GET['query'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("unblocked_search");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM unblocked_search WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<a href='".$a['link']."'>".$a['title']."</a><p>".$a['description']."</p><hr/>";
    }

  } else {
    echo "Oh no! Nothing was found.";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` out the query, like `echo "SELECT * FROM unblocked_search ..."`?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Several things. First phpAdmin is a tool for accessing and defining a database and it's parts (tables, etc.), and not something you use to create apps. Second, you're using mysql functions (depreciated) instead of mysqli functions. Third, you're not using prepared statements, so your code would be subject to SQL Injection.

Comment: Also, you're not assigning your connection to a variable, so you don't have the parameter needed in other mysql calls (mysql_query 1st parameter).

Answer (score 0):

<s>The PHP `mysql_query` function takes *two* arguments. The first argument is the query string. The second argument is the connection.</s>

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> As @Barmar notes in a comment below, the second parameter to `mysql_query` is optional. So the answer above likely has no bearing on the observed behavior.

As far as debugging the issue, I recommend that you first switch to using mysqli_ or PDO.  And then add code to check for the return from function calls; test whether the connection to the database is successful or not. Test whether the execution of a query is successful or not.

And enable PHP error reporting.  If there's an error happening, you want to know about it. Don't have your code put its pinky finger to the corner of its mouth and Dr.Evil style

> Scott Evil: Wait, aren't you even going to watch them? They could get away!
>
> Dr. Evil: No no no, I'm going to leave them alone and not actually witness them dying, I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?

---

NOTES:

As indicated in the documentation, the mysql_ interface functions are *deprecated* (and removed in PHP 7.)  New development should use either mysqli_ or PDO.  There are mysqli_ functions that correspond to most of the deprecated mysql_ functions, though there are some differences. Note the order of parameters is different for mysqli_query.

This is the documentation for the mysqli_query function:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Also, best practice is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*.  If we absolutely have a need to include potentially unsafe values into the SQL text, then when we do that, the values *must* be properly escaped. There are functions available specifically designed for this:

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

(NOTE: That's a reference to the mysqli_ function.  Do *not* mix the mysql_ and mysqli_ interface functions; use one or the other. (Actually, don't use mysql_ at all, just use mysqli_.)

If we supply values through bind placeholders in prepared statements, those do not need to be escaped.

```
$search = $_GET['query'];

if(!$dbh = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database') {
   // connect failed
   die( mysqli_connect error() );
}

// static SQL text, not vulnerable to SQL Injection
$sql = "SELECT * FROM unblocked_search WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%')";

if(!$sth = mysqli_prepare($dbh, $sql)) {
   // prepare failed
   die( mysqi_error($dbh) );
} else {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'s',$search);
   if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sth);
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
         echo "\n<br> $row['name'] <br> $row['description'] ";
      }
   } else {
      // execute failed
      die( mysqli_error($dbh) );
   }
}
```

NOTE:  We are using `die` as a placeholder, in place of more appropriate error handling (logging information, returning an error page to the user, etc.

Comment: The second argument to `mysql_query` is optional. It defaults to the last connection opened, so it's almost always omitted if you only work with one connection.